# ISPConfig wont accept new certificate

Tags: ssl, ispconfig, ispconfig-3

I was using certificate which expired. I requested new one with new private key and request file.

But when I add new certificate to ISPConfig vhost, even after running

```
 /usr/local/ispconfig/server/server.sh
```

the new certificate wont be accepted by ISPConfig and is still using the old one which expired, so my site is not working with HTTPS. Is there possibility that ISPConfig have this old certificate stored somewhere?

I also deleted content of SSL folder in my vhost but did not worked either. 
Site is working with generated Let's Encrypt certificate.

Comment: Delirium, Do you want to install paid SSL Certificate (Rapid SSL Certificate or Multi-domain SSL certificate) on your server or Free SSL Certificate (Let's Encrypt)? I faced the same issue and I fixed it by using the ISPConfig update script. 

Please let me know if you need the steps to update the ISPConfig script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same error and I fixed it by applying the second method. I've mentioned both methods for you. Please try any to renew your SSL Certificate.

Method 1:

Create a new ISPConfig 3 SSL Certificate with OpenSSL
Login to your server on the shell as a root user. Before we create a new SSL Cert, backup the current ones. SSL Certs are security-sensitive so I'll store the backup in the /root/ folder.

```
# tar pcfz /root/ispconfig_ssl_backup.tar.gz /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/ssl
# chmod 600 /root/ispconfig_ssl_backup.tar.gz

Now create a new SSL Certificate key, Certificate Request (csr) and a self-signed certificate.

# cd /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/ssl
# openssl genrsa -des3 -out ispserver.key 4096
# openssl req -new -key ispserver.key -out ispserver.csr
# openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in ispserver.csr \
-signkey ispserver.key -out ispserver.crt
# openssl rsa -in ispserver.key -out ispserver.key.insecure
# mv ispserver.key ispserver.key.secure
# mv ispserver.key.insecure ispserver.key

Restart Apache to load the new SSL Certificate.

# service apache2 restart
```

Method 2:

Renew the SSL Certificate with the ISPConfig installer
The alternative way to get a new SSL Certificate is to use the ISPConfig update script.
Download ISPConfig to the /tmp folder, unpack the archive and start the update script.

```
# cd /tmp
# wget http://www.ispconfig.org/downloads/ISPConfig-3-stable.tar.gz
# tar xvfz ISPConfig-3-stable.tar.gz
# cd ispconfig3_install/install
# php -q update.php

The update script will ask the following question during the update:

Create new ISPConfig SSL certificate (yes,no) [no]:
Answer "yes" here and the SSL Certificate creation dialog will start.
```

Thank you!